# Bootstrap modal not working when show/hide is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed that when I open and close modal dialogue rapidly modal dialogue will sooner or later fail to open until webpage is reloaded.

I open the dialogue with the following code:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

And close it with:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

As I said the problem occurs if I open and close modal dialogue rapidly (2 times per second). I did some researching and found out that the problem could be caused by async nature of show/hide.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to tackle this issue?

Comment: have you checked your console? is there error ?

Comment: create a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

There are various events that modal will trigger when its visible or hidden. Use these to determine if modal is visible or hidden, then trigger show/hide.

```
// When modal visible
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
});

// When modal hidden
$('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
});
```